# Visual Basic - Application hangup when serial is closed

Tags: vb.net, serial-port, arduino, microcontroller

my application performes serial communication with a microcontroller.

Here is the event:

```
Public Event DataReceived As IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventHandler
```

Handling the Event:

```
Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived
    MyReceivedSerialData = SerialPort1.ReadExisting
    Me.Invoke(New EventHandler(AddressOf SerialThreadHandler))
End Sub
```

The SerialThreadHandler() processes the received data...

However the user has also the option to disconnect from the serial interface.
In this case this procedure is executed:

```
Public Sub MyDisconnectAndClose()
    If frmUploadData.SerialPort1.IsOpen = True Then
        Try
            frmUploadData.SerialPort1.Close()
            frmUploadData.Close()
            frmUploadData.Dispose()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

If there is data transmitted or received during the disconnect, the whole application will hang.

This is a known issue and I am not the first one who encounters this...

As a possible solution, there is the recommandation, to use BeginInvoke instead of Invoke.

Invoke = synchronus
BeginInvoke = asynchronus

When I use BeginInvoke

```
Me.BeginInvoke(New EventHandler(AddressOf SerialThreadHandler))
```

The disconnect does not cause a hangup any more, but due to the asynchronus communication the communication does stop at random points - this is definitely a side effect or issue of the asynchronous communication, because the application is extensively receiving and transmitting data...

Is there any other way, to create a workaround or solution for this problem?

Comment: This is like filling a bucket from a faucet, removing the bucket and hoping the floor doesn't get wet.  You of course close the faucet first.

Comment: Which .net framework are you using?

Comment: I decided to use .Net Framework 3.5 Clinet Profile...

Comment: According to http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3e64f562-e74b-4213-8019-e69f54fc0d74/warning-serialport-in-net-35?forum=Vsexpressvb 3.5 is quite buggy.  They suggest dropping down to 2.0 (you may have to remove references to linq)

Comment: What do you think is the best .NET framework, if you think to distribute a software? I did the decision to use .NET framework 3.5 based on the thaught that even people with older frameworks may use the software without the need for updating the framework...